# ServiceStack CustomAuthenticationMvc Admin password?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, servicestack

I'm running the ServiceStack Use Cases example of CustomAuthenticationMvc but whe I'm try to Log in I pur in the asp mvc Log in page

User: admin
password  : 123

but displays an error msg (Invalid username or password), so in the project of CustomValidation but with ASP.NET those are de Username and password for access the HelloService... so what are the UserName and Password in the CustomAuthenticationMvc for access the HelloService?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at AppHost.cs, you can see how the authentication is being performed:

```
public class CustomCredentialsAuthProvider : CredentialsAuthProvider
{
    public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password)
    {
        if (!Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password)) return false;
        ....
    }
}
```

So it is using the membership provider framework to authenticate users.

By default it's going use SimpleMembership (see e.g. http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx), with the default connection coming from the web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-CustomAuthenticationMvc-20121011213234;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

You'll notice the DB (`aspnet-CustomAuthenticationMvc-20121011213234`) - it doesn't actually exist.  You'll have to create it via `Server Explorer` within Visual Studio.

Then you'll have to create a user within the DB.  A quick way to do that is to put the following:

```
if (!WebSecurity.UserExists("testuser"))
    WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("testuser", "secret");
```

in a seed method somewhere.  For simplicity's sake you could just put it in the `Login` method of your `AccountController`.

---

Alternatively, if you can't be bothered with all that, you could just mimic the code that's in the CustomAuthentication project.

i.e. replace

```
if (!Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password)) return false;
```

with

```
if (!CheckInDB(userName, password)) return false;

...

private bool CheckInDB(string userName, string password)
{
    if (userName != "admin" && userName != "user") return false;
    return password == "123";
}
```